# Properties of solutions to system of linear equations with diagnonally dominant, positive (definite) matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, positive-definite, tridiagonal-matrices

Consider a system of linear equations $Ax = b$, where
\begin{eqnarray}
%
A & = & \left[ \begin{array}{ccccc}
2 &    1   &        &        &   \\
1 &    4   &    1   &        &   \\
  & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots &   \\
  &        &    1   &    4   & 1 \\
  &        &        &    1   & 2 \\
\end{array} \right] \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n} 
\end{eqnarray}
and $n\geq 3$.

I would like to prove the following two statements, where the inequalities are element-wise:
\begin{eqnarray}
b \geq 0 & ~~~~ \Longrightarrow ~~~~ & x \geq 0 \\
b > 0 & \Longrightarrow & x > 0 ~ .
\end{eqnarray}

APPARENT FACTS: The matrix $A$ is

- square
- symmetric
- tri-diagonal
- non-negative (element-wise)
- positive definite
- invertible
- strictly diagonally dominant.

I have tried proving the two statements based on the fact that each element of $A$ is non-negative, but my attempts at proofs are not water-tight. The matrix $A$ is positive-definite and symmetric, and so is its inverse, but I was not able to exploit this. Any assistance and insight is much appreciated. If you know of any further properties of the system of equations related to the specifics of $A$ I would also appreciate your insight.

Answer (score 0):

You are essentially trying to prove that the inverse of $A$ is a positive matrix, which is not true as you can check by computing the inverse for, say, $n=3$: [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=inverse%20of%20%7B%7B2,1,0%7D,%7B1,4,1%7D,%7B0,1,2%7D%7D)

You can use the inverse to directly find a counterexample: when $$b=\left[\begin{array}{c}1\\0\\0\end{array}\right]$$
we have
$$x = \left[\begin{array}{c}\frac{7}{12}\\\frac{-1}{6}\\\frac{1}{12}\end{array}\right] \not\geq 0.$$